# RAPL on AWS cloud VM? No intel_rapl and related files in directory /sys/class/powercapp

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, intel, energy

I want to use the Intel RAPL interface to record the energy consumption on CPUs. I am using two servers: an AWS EC2 instance and a physical machine.
However, I found that there is no `powercap` directory under the directory `/sys/class` on the AWS EC2 instance. After I changed the Linux kernel to version 5.13.19 and have the Intel RAPL configured, there is a `power cap` directory under `/sys/class`. But there is no `intel-rapl` under `/sys/class/powercap`, so I can not use the RAPL interface as well.

This is what I have under `/sys/class/powercap` on the AWS EC2 instance:

```
$ ls /sys/class/powercap
dtpm
```

This is what I have under `/sys/class/powercap` on the physical machine, and is also what I expect on the AWS EC2 instance:

```
$ ls /sys/class/powercap
dtpm  intel-rapl  intel-rapl:0  intel-rapl:0:0  intel-rapl:1  intel-rapl:1:0
```

These are the RAPL-related modules on the AWS EC2 instance, which are the same on my physical machine:

```
$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name *rapl*
/lib/modules/5.13.19/kernel/drivers/powercap/intel_rapl_common.ko
/lib/modules/5.13.19/kernel/drivers/powercap/intel_rapl_msr.ko
/lib/modules/5.13.19/kernel/drivers/thermal/intel/int340x_thermal/processor_thermal_rapl.ko
/lib/modules/5.13.19/kernel/arch/x86/events/rapl.ko
```

I can tell from `sudo dmidecode -t4 | grep Socket.Designation: | wc -l` that there are 4 CPU sockets on the EC2 instance. The cpu for the EC2 instance is Intel Xeon. RAPL is supported for these cpus. So there should be something more under `/sys/class/powercap`!

I am using the Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu 18.04) Version 61.2 for the AWS EC2 instance.

Does anyone know why I cannot use powercap and RAPL on the AWS EC2 instance? Is it because the EC2 instance is a virtual machine and the RAPL interface is not supported by the virtual machine? Or have I missed out any steps? I would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: https://medium.com/teads-engineering/estimating-aws-ec2-instances-power-consumption-c9745e347959 was the first google hit for `AWS RAPL`.   That says "some MSRs are not accessible anymore on modern EC2 instances that use newer hypervisors (KVM)".